# "unlimited admission for..." in advertising

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence natural in advertising?

> Happy Pass:  Unlimited admission for two adults and up to six children under age 
>                12 for 12 months - $120 - includes a free ice cream per guest on each 
>                visit.

Do you think the subject of the above sentence is too long? Also, is it natural for the price to be inserted where it is?

Having looked at the above sentence. do you find the following version more natural?

> Happy Pass:  $120. Unlimited admission for two adults and up to six children 
>                      under age 12 for 12 months!
>                      Including a free ice cream per guest on each visit!

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "in advertising"? On a coupon?  In a voice-over on a TV commercial?  In a magazine spot that takes up a quarter page, with this text in fine-print at the bottom of a picture as disclaimer?

Comment: in promotional writing, on a webpage,  for example.

Comment: I consider your second version an improvement. But someone could easily say the better version is the one that "submerges" the price in a soup of text.

Comment: Do you prefer the 2nd version because the subject of the 1st is too long? The 2nd evades the problem by using fragments.

Comment: I preferred it for info-presentation reasons, not grammatical ones.  Your version is actually ungrammatical. **including** should be **includes**. Even elliptical ad-speak sentences require a tensed verb. But if you make that change, your version is better, I think.

Comment: What about "Happy Pass: $120. Unlimited admission for two adults and up to six children under age 12 for 12 months. Plus a free ice cream per guest on each visit!"? I am still using fragments because I've noticed some advertising sentences do drop verbs (e.g. 30-day no-hassle refunds available.)

Comment: "Plus a free..." is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The initial sentence is fine.

It's not too long - I have no trouble parsing it. I don't think there is a long grammatical subject in the first one. Instead there are three  fragments with implied (and short) subjects:  "Happy Pass: (It gives) Unlimited admission... (It costs) $120 - (It) Includes a free ice ..."

You can put the price in the middle (some advertising likes to "hide" the price) It is a separate sentence, with implied subject. I'm not keen on the exclamation marks in the alternative, and the present tense, with implied subject works better for me than the fragment starting "including".

I think this is a matter of taste, but I see no great need to change from the original.

Comment: It's not a sentence; it's a phrase, James.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's really either a sentence or a phrase.  There are multiple fragments, and we can make sense of the meaning. I count three fragments.